# I can't get my JSON request to work

Tags: javascript, json, request

I have created a url that I need to pass to police data API.

```
var api_url="http://policeapi2.rkh.co.uk/api/locate-neighbourhood?q="+latlon;
document.write(api_url);
```

The URL works when you manually input it into a browser, but I need some JavaScript that sends the API request and spits it onto the page. My JavaScript is ok but I have no knowledge of jQuery.

Thank you in advance, please keep it simple brainy folk.

Comment: ... `window.location="http://policeapi2.rkh.co.uk/api/locate-neighbourhood?q="+latlon;`?

Comment: Sounds almost as if you're trying an X-domain ajax request... only: there is no JSON in your snippet, no ajax calls being made, nothing really. Just assigning a string to a variable and then writing to the document (1/2 chance of wiping the entire DOM with that BTW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following.. its is working
JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9AZyZ/

```
function abc(latLong){
     $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
                        data: {
                            q: "select * from json where url ='http://policeapi2.rkh.co.uk/api/locate-neighbourhood?q="+latLong+"'",
                            format: "json"
                        },
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (data) {

                        alert(JSON.stringify(data));


                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Sorry no data found.");
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: That works great! But how would I dynamically get the users location and add it to the URL?

Comment: i have edited. Call function pass parameters and use. And dont forget to accept answer if it has helped you

Comment: Thats great! Im struggling to pass my latLong value to it though,
http://jsfiddle.net/9AZyZ/1/